# How to properly arrange this type of schema?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, normalization

I want to allow the user to be able to create whatever metric they want and record values for it over time. The only action outside of that would be to be able to view the data trend for a chosen metric / timeframe.

I structured my tables like this:

```
Table: Metric
Fields: id int prim key, name text

Table: MetricPoint
Fields: id int prim key, metric_id int (foreign key to Metric.id), value real, timestamp long
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Or should I be dynamically making new tables for each metric that is added? Or making them columns?

I had been told this current arrangement was bad because it used Entity–attribute–value modeling, which is considered an anti-pattern apparently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT make new tables for each metric.  Do not add new columns for new metrics.  Your approach seems to be correct.

When you can enter new data without having to redesign/create new objects, then you are on the right path.

Regarding EAV: that is more or less when you don't know what the schema is, so you try to build a schema that can cover whatever might need to be covered. It's a nightmare and shouldn't really be used. In your case, you know exactly what the schema is (metric, metric attribute), just not what the values are, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Someone had mentioned that the way I structured it was incorrect because it was an anti-pattern called... something I can't seem to find anymore. EAX form? Edit: EAV form, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: It's a standard 1:M relationship and is perfectly correct per your description of what it needs to track.  Ask whoever told you that for a detailed explanation then post back here and we can tell you why they are incorrect (really, this is about as basic as it gets)

Comment: Ok, just took a look at your link... BS is what I say, but that's just me.  I'd do it the way you describe in your question, as would the vast majority of competent database developers that I know.

Comment: Do i need to add any additional index to speed anything up? I am guessing no because foreign key automatically gets indexed I think, but just asking. Maybe timestamp UNIQUE?

Comment: To clarify, what you have suggested is not an EAV model.  Allowing users to describe their own metrics is not in context of an EAV - what you have is a very basic, highly common scenario for the most commonly used 1:M relationship.  An EAV is something else entirely and not of concern here.

Comment: I forget offhand for SQLite, but usually FK indexes aren't created by default.  It's not likely to hurt, so feel free to add it, otherwise no, you're fine (PK indexes are created automatically).  Otherwise don't worry about indexes much until there becomes a performance issue.  You're good for now.

Comment: Based on what I read, I assume EAV is more like when you have a large number of columns to describe something, such that most of the values would end up being null, so the columns get encoded as fields instead which become harder to query later

Comment: So I think they said this was EAV model because the "metrics" should be column names, in other words

Comment: EAV is more or less when you don't know what the schema is, so you try to build a schema that can cover whatever might need to be covered.  It's a nightmare and shouldn't really be used.  In your case, you know exactly what the *schema* is (metric, metric attribute), just not what the values are, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Makes sense; that is reassuring. Thank you!

Comment: Using column names for metrics would be non-normalized and is a very much the sign of an amateur database developer (I can only guess at someone that knows EAV but thinks that having a metric per column is normalized!)  Glad to help.